# php- javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i got a sales web site each time i press "sales" button it it will open a new frame.
there is a possibility  for more then one frame at the same time.
my problem is i want to close the frame after i click enter and home page to be updated  provided all the other pending sales frames are remain open....
i tried to do so with window concept also no use
so any body can geve a solution 
regards

Comment: have you given thought about using modal dialog..?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles for questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at ThickBox or jQuery's user interface plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with Extrakun, especially use of JQuery. I did a similar project like this a couple of years ago for an Intranet tool. You could possibly also do it with iFrames, maybe consider [Fancybox](http://www.fancybox.net) too for neat pop out overlays.